# How to reset variables state when moving between pages (Chrome Specific)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-history

I am working with the html5 history api. When I click a link to a new page, and then click the back button. I am seeing variables who are retaining their state between page loads.

Example:

```
(function(namespace){
    var singlePageSessionId = 0;
    singlePageSessionId = new Date().getTime();

    namespace.SinglePageSessionId = function(){
        return singlePageSessionId; 
    }
}(window.namespace = window.namespace || {}))
```

That singlePageSessionId variable should be set once per actual page load. However when I click back, and then check the value of namespace.SinglePageSessionId it retains the timestamp of when I first navigated to the site. Since I am re-executing the javascript I expect the variable to be reset.

I either have a fundamental mis-understanding of how the javascript engine works between pages or there is some weird behavior here.

Is there a way to make sure the variables get reset ?

Answer (score 0):

How hard I tried I could not reproduce the issue you are talking about.
Locally I had no problem at all going back and receive new value.
This is what I did http://jsfiddle.net/itaymer/bqg3azx8/

```
(function(namespace) {
    var singlePageSessionId = new Date().getTime();

    namespace.SinglePageSessionId = function(){
        return singlePageSessionId; 
    }
}(window.namespace = window.namespace || {}));

document.querySelector(".pageSessionId").innerHTML = window.namespace.SinglePageSessionId();
```

Maybe you failed to supply the whole situation information?